# PySpark DataFrame Issues

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am building a pipeline for a Spark dataset and am getting the following error message:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

because the class of my dataframe is:

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

instead of

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.DataFrame'>
```

How do I get the right class so I can use the .transform() function in my pipeline? Below is from the docs:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the spark version you are using?
transform was added in v3.0.0 so that's important.

I couldn't manage to replicate your code, please share an example.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema="mock string")

type(df)
>> pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame

df.transform
>> <bound method DataFrame.transform of DataFrame[mock: string]>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was using pre-3.0 and banging my head on the desk.